# Converting PHP code (to encode a WebServices API HASH) to COLDFUSION

Tags: php, encoding, coldfusion, sha512

I'm working on a ColdFusion site that needs to talk to another system through Webservices. For the other system I have a sample in PHP about how to generate a SHA512 based hash, and I'm trying to replicate the same function in ColdFusion but it is just not working.

The sample includes a string and key, and the expected encoded outcome. But I do not get the same encoded string with ColdFusion. Maybe I'm missing a ToBase64 or another conversion function somewhere, but I'm out of ideas and really need help to get this working.

Any help would be soo much appreciated.

### Here's the PHP Sample Code

```
//signature to acquire a session
$apiId = '1lie8ficql9h5';
$apiSecret = 'j6hriaKY2iZi+Y2uo9JJldmO1Bq79XB8d1v2uHzAK0Zvy972mIs8ThsJSQeDlZJz+HzmLD6Q1MUZb5X1Zf9MzQ==';

//build the string to sign
//note the order of the entries is important.
//The http headers must be in alphabetical order by key name
$httpMethod = 'POST';
$apiKey = 'x-csod-api-key:'.$apiId;
$httpUrl = '/services/api/sts/session';

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$date = 'x-csod-date:'.date('Y-m-d').'T'.date('H:i:s').'.000';
$stringToSign = $httpMethod."\n".$apiKey."\n".$date."\n".$httpUrl;

/* produces the following string:
*  POST\nx-csod-api-key:1lie8ficql9h5\nx-csod-date:2015-09-08T11:27:32.000\n/services/api/sts/session
*/

//Generate the signature
$secretKey = base64_decode($apiSecret);
$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha512', $stringToSign, $secretKey, true));

/*
* signature produced:
* 3x5ETGSoqJa4vLl8gOFzdhxReOS0k8Nk2CpKVFN2A60ItF8wfP2tr+GUY2mELXjL90B57B5imLIrzou3ZQMfqQ==
*/
```

### Here's the ColdFusion code I have, but it's not producing the same encoded string:

```
<cfoutput>

<cfset api_id=      "1lie8ficql9h5">
<cfset api_secret=  "j6hriaKY2iZi+Y2uo9JJldmO1Bq79XB8d1v2uHzAK0Zvy972mIs8ThsJSQeDlZJz+HzmLD6Q1MUZb5X1Zf9MzQ==">

<cfset api_string= "POST\nx-csod-api-key:1lie8ficql9h5\nx-csod-date:2015-09-08T11:27:32.000\n/services/api/sts/session">

<cfset temp_key= ToString(ToBinary( api_secret))>

<cfset temp_signature= HMAC( api_string, temp_key, "HMACSHA512", "UTF-8")>
<cfset temp_signature1= ToBase64( temp_signature)>


api_string:<br> #api_string#<br><br>
temp_signature:<br> #temp_signature#<br>
temp_signature1:<br> #temp_signature1#<br><br>

EXPECTED: (Copied from the PHP Sample code)<br>
3x5ETGSoqJa4vLl8gOFzdhxReOS0k8Nk2CpKVFN2A60ItF8wfP2tr+GUY2mELXjL90B57B5imLIrzou3ZQMfqQ==
</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two things that go wrong here:

1. `hmac()` in ColdFusion returns the hash in hexadecimal. `hmac(..., true)` in PHP returns the hash as binary.
2. There are new lines (line feed) `\n` in the message you want to hash. ColdFusion does not automatically convert them. PHP does (when enclosed in double quotes `"`).

Solution:

1. Use `binaryDecode(hmac, "HEX")` to convert the hash to binary in ColdFusion.
2. Use `#chr(10)#` instead of `\n` in ColdFusion.

---

Here is a version for both languages:

PHP:

```
$apiSecret = 'j6hriaKY2iZi+Y2uo9JJldmO1Bq79XB8d1v2uHzAK0Zvy972mIs8ThsJSQeDlZJz+HzmLD6Q1MUZb5X1Zf9MzQ==';
$stringToSign = "POST\nx-csod-api-key:1lie8ficql9h5\nx-csod-date:2015-09-08T11:27:32.000\n/services/api/sts/session";

$secretKey = base64_decode($apiSecret);
$signature = base64_encode(
    hash_hmac('sha512', $stringToSign, $secretKey, true)
);

echo $signature;
```

ColdFusion:

```
<cfset apiSecret = 'j6hriaKY2iZi+Y2uo9JJldmO1Bq79XB8d1v2uHzAK0Zvy972mIs8ThsJSQeDlZJz+HzmLD6Q1MUZb5X1Zf9MzQ=='>
<cfset stringToSign = 'POST#chr(10)#x-csod-api-key:1lie8ficql9h5#chr(10)#x-csod-date:2015-09-08T11:27:32.000#chr(10)#/services/api/sts/session'>

<cfset secretKey = toBinary(apiSecret)>
<cfset signature = toBase64(
    binaryDecode(
        hmac(stringToSign, secretKey, 'HMACSHA512'),
        'HEX'
    )
)>

<cfoutput>#signature#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Great answer (and excellent first question! Welcome to S.O. :)